# Bash - [: =: unary operator expected during trap execution

Tags: bash

I am trying to use trap in order to run a clean-app jar in case the main app jar exists successfully (0 exit code) :

```
trap "exit_code=$?; if [ "${exit_code}" = "0" ]; then java -jar /clean-app.jar; fi" EXIT

java -jar /main-app.jar
```

but I am getting the following error and not sure I'm getting the reason behind it :

> /bin/bash: line 1: [: =: unary operator expected

Could someone share a pointer please ? Thank you

Comment: I also tried `trap "exit_code=$?; if [ "${exit_code}" = "0" ]; then java -jar /clean-app.jar; fi" EXIT`but getting error : `/bin/bash: line 1: [: -eq: unary operator expected`

Comment: Runs perfectly on my side, with bas h 4.4.23(1)

Comment: The problem is the double quotes; they cause `$?` and `${exit_code}` to be evaluated when your trap is being defined instead of when it's being run. Moreover, they mean the double quotes _inside_ the string are ending the double quotes from outside it, instead of being part of the statement defined as a trap. chepner's advice to define a function is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest double quotes like this. Here, you can switch to single quotes for the outer layer. You'll want to do this anyway because you need to prevent `$?` from being expanded before `trap` is called.

```
trap 'exit_code=$?; if [ "${exit_code}" = "0" ]; then java -jar /clean-app.jar; fi' EXIT
```

Better yet, define a *function* first.

```
handler () {
    exit_code=$?
    if [ "$exit_code" = 0 ]; then java -jar /clean-app.jar; fi
}

trap handler EXIT
```

In either case, you don't really need `exit_code`, as you don't need the original exit code after the test. You can also use `-eq`, since `$?` is guaranteed to be an integer.

```
handler () {
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && java -jar /clean-app.jar
}
```